# Advanced Calculator features Tkinter GUI and variable error

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Edit: I fixed the error, etc, with which this post was concerned, and now I am trying a different way to achieve advanced features I was originally going for. This time I have a display, and a display function. The buttons call the update function by inserting text into said display. I was wondering how I could use this function, and maybe `textvariable =`so that I can both change my buttons' text from 1, 2, 3, 4... 9, 0 to A, B, C, D...I, J. My code is below, any help would be appreciated. :)

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.title('Calculator')



displayb = Entry(root)
displayb.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 6)


mode = 0

i = 0


'''def update():
    global mode
    if mode == 0:
        mode = 1
    else:
        mode = 0
    return'''
def display(e):
    global i
    displayb.insert(i,e)
    i += 1

txt1 = StringVar()
a = '1' if mode == 0 else 'A'
one = Button(root, text = '1', command = lambda : display(1))
txt1.set(a)
one.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
two = Button(root, text = '2', command = lambda : display(2))
two.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
three = Button(root, text = '3', command = lambda : display(3))
three.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
four = Button(root, text = '4', command = lambda : display(4))
four.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
five = Button(root, text = '5', command = lambda : display(5))
five.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
six = Button(root, text = '6', command = lambda : display(6))
six.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
seven = Button(root, text = '7', command = lambda : display(7))
seven.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
eight = Button(root, text = '8', command = lambda : display(8))
eight.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
nine = Button(root, text = '9', command = lambda : display(9))
nine.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
zero = Button(root, text = '0', command = lambda : display(0))
zero.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
'''shift = Button(root, text = 'sft', command = lambda : mode = 1 if mode == 0 else 0)
shift.grid(row = 2, column = 1)'''


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

When providing the `command` parameter a value, you need to give it a reference to your function by just giving it the function name.

```
shift = Button(root, text = 'sft', command = update())
```

Here you have `()` at the end of it which is calling your function. Either remove the `()` or use `lambda` like you did earlier.

Now, the reason you are getting the error you are is because `mode` is a `global` variable, defined outside your `update` function. So if you want to update the variable then you need to let it know that `mode` is `global`

```
def update():
    global mode
    if mode == 0:
        mode = 1
    else:
        mode = 0
    return mode
```

Also note that unless you will call this function somewhere else, you can't retrieve the return value on Button press.

More info on [global and local scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/4831822).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I'll give it a shot Thanks very much again!